# Self sign SSL certificate for my mobile app?

Tags: tls, mobile

My mobile (iOS and Android) connects to my server via a REST API over HTTP. I would like that HTTP to be secure, so HTTPS seems to be the obvious choice. All of the questions about self signing SSL certificates warn about how users of the a website won't trust you if you self-sign and they don't know you. But in this case, I don't need my users to trust me, but rather the app has to trust me. Are there any problems with this approach or should I just fork out the money to one of the CAs so I don't have to worry about it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899079/custom-ssl-handling-stopped-working-on-android-2-2-froyo

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not asking about client implementation, but rather the security of the system.

Comment: @Max Could you please provide any link to implement this approach. I want to do the same but cant find anything to do with both app and server side

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your particular use case, a self signed cert would be fine.

As you control the app, you do not have to use certificates recognized by browsers, which is the key point of a certificated by a trusted CA.

Functionally, there is no difference in security. See: [Does Self-signed certificate differ from CA from a security point of view?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/does-self-signed-certificate-differ-from-ca-from-a-security-point-of-view)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a SSL cert for something like $10. Not getting one creates far more hassle than that money is worth.

You can write code to securely verify the self-signed SSL certificate in your app, but the potential for making mistakes is greater than zero, and therefore not really worth it.

Comment: Keep in mind that a $10 SSL cert isn't likely to be for a particularly reputable CA, though.

Comment: A valid SSL cert is a valid SSL cert. If the root is trusted by the client/browser, there's no difference.

Comment: Precisely. A lot of less-reputable CAs don't make it into some devices, whereas the big CAs (e.g. Verisign / Globalsign) are highly likely to be in all of them. Plus you'd figure that the big authorities are the ones to be throwing lots of money at HSMs and other expensive security measures.

Comment: Please give me some references about real, and at least somewhat-popular CA-s that are not supported by actual clients? Of course there are differences in security measures, but in real usage (especially for a mobile app API) a $10 Comodo cert is no less secure than a $1000 Verisign Extended Validation certificate.

Comment: Wasn't aware that Comodo was selling certs for $10 these days. I was considering discount CAs like CACert and InstantSSL. And you're right in saying the cert itself gives no extra security; I was referring to the security of the CA itself.

Comment: Yes, but even that doesn't really make the certificates  less reliable. If a medium/big, trusted CA is really hacked, hackers can still issue certs that are valid for any site (until the CA root cert is revoked by clients). The way to detect that in a mobile app would be to verify the certificate being returned by the server, but I would certainly say that's not required for common usage. (Plus, I think it would break in situations where SSL connections are proxied).

Comment: I don't see why a $10 SSL cert will make a difference over a self signed one in this case. If you aren't using a browser for the HTTPS connection, you are going to have to write code to verify the cert anyway.

Comment: (Non-browser HTTP libraries verify SSL certificates too…)

Comment: @JoelL Exactly. Use the same library to verify your self signed cert. No one is suggesting to write code to generate your own certs.

Comment: I have to say I don't understand the relevance of this answer.

Comment: @Ayrx: that $10/year may turn out to be cheaper than what you'd spend on, say, renting a box in a bank's vault to store your root certificate's private key in.  And if something goes wrong and you need revocation, a commercial CA will already have the infrastructure and procedures in place, so you can concentrate on fixing the specifics of your service that may have contributed to the breach, and spend much less effort on frantically figuring out the intricacies and pitfalls of ad hoc revocation.

Comment: @dig You'd store your root certificate in the same private box that you're storing the data whose access the root certificate is protecting. As for revocation, I don't see how things would be any less complicated. It's easy to revoke your own certificate, just tell your server not to allow it. Since he writes the code for his own app, he'll need to write code in there to handle revocations, regardless of whether he used a cert from a CA or his own self-signed. Their infrastructure is only helpful if you're actually using it. He is not.

Answer (score 2):

Security of the system is dependent on client implementation. All a certificate inherently does is provide an "agreed encrypted communication protocol". How secure the communication is in actuality is whether or not there is someone playing "man in the middle".

So how do you verify that the certificate received is the same certificate that the source wants you to use? That's either through a 3rd party verifier (which is what comes with payment to a CA) or through the client who (from a previously hard coded implementation) already whats what the cert should look like.

gluck!

Answer (score 0):

Using self-singed certificates is generally a bad idea. Consider the scenario: you hardcode your certificate fingerprint to make sure there's no MITM. Imagine that your server gets compromised, and you need to revoke the certificate, and issue a new one.

Think of the consequences to your user base - having to update a new version of the app.

Is it possible? It is, although your mileage may vary, as they say. You work out of the risk profile of the data you're transferring, and the nature of the transactions. For example, if you've got a game and transfer your game high scores only, then it should be OK. However, if you start transacting other things, like user registration, then it wouldn't be that good.

Comment: In practice, you would not hardcode the fingerprint of the web certificate, but a self-signed CA certificate, use that to generate the webserver certificate, and use reasonable precautions against the CA certificate getting compromised.  If you expect to only have to generate a very small number of webserver certificates, you can typically get away by keeping the root certificate's private key completely offline, which may make securing it even a bit easier than what commercial certification agencies have to deal with.